# Configure Neo4j with Java

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

This is my first attempt at Neo4j with java. I have used maven to resolve all the dependencies. My code looks like this.

```
package com.hp.neo4jdemo;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Main {

    public enum NodeType implements Label {
        Person, Course;
    }

    public enum RelationType implements RelationshipType {
        Knows, BelongsTo
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphDatabaseFactory graphDatabaseFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = graphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\\Program Files\\Neo4j Community");

        try(Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Node bobNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            bobNode.setProperty("PId", 5001);
            bobNode.setProperty("Name", "Bob");
            bobNode.setProperty("Age", 23);

            Node aliceNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            aliceNode.setProperty("PId", 5002);
            aliceNode.setProperty("Name", "Alice");

            Node eveNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            eveNode.setProperty("Name", "Eve");

            Node itNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Course);
            itNode.setProperty("Id", 1);
            itNode.setProperty("Name", "IT Beginners");
            itNode.setProperty("Location", "Room 153");

            Node electronicsNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Course);
            electronicsNode.setProperty("Name", "Electronics Advanced");

            bobNode.createRelationshipTo(aliceNode, RelationType.Knows);

            Relationship bobRelIt = bobNode.createRelationshipTo(itNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            bobRelIt.setProperty("Function", "Student");

            Relationship bobRelElectronics = bobNode.createRelationshipTo(electronicsNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            bobRelElectronics.setProperty("Function", "Supply Teacher");

            Relationship aliceRelIt = aliceNode.createRelationshipTo(itNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            aliceRelIt.setProperty("Function", "Teacher");

            tx.success();
        }
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }
}
```

When I run the code it executes successfully, however when I crosscheck the nodes from the back end I don't see any.

I am using windows 7 64 bit and Neo4j community server. The Neo4j server is installed with all default configurations.

I am performing the following steps to check if data is added to the database:

1. Execute the above code
2. Start the community server
3. Check the url http://localhost:7474/browser/
4. Execute the query 'MATCH(n) RETURN n;' which returns no nodes

Could anyone please let me know where I am going wrong or may be something wrong with the configuration.

Comment: You should check that when you create EmbeddedGraphDatabase path actually points to database. Usually database is stored in `$HEO_HOME/data/graph.db` folder. Also - consider using tool for connecting to Neo4j server, instead of using Embedded database.

Comment: @FylmTM - This is very first attempt at neo4j. I am really not aware what will be the value of $NEO_HOME (I will check it though). If I am not able to find out the value, could you please let me know what it is.  I have installed neo4j with all default configurations in windows 7.

Comment: Where you're creating the embedded DB is a strange location.  Almost certainly, when you start the server, it's not pointing to that location.  Triple-check that first.

Comment: I am not aware of the location. Could you tell me where it could be. I am using all default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code 
 GraphDatabaseService graphDb = graphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community");
for

```html
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = graphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/Program Files/Neo4j Community");
```

and also may i know how to set your noe4j environment path for your system.